# Hibernate dynamic entity model

Tags: java, hibernate

I am creating a Java application that utilizes a JPA annotated model - the core model -. On top of these entities, at runtime, I would like to add a jar file from an external source that contains some other JPA classes definitions and mappings. The imported archive might change its class structure and mappings, but it is the application's duty to refresh the entire schema when changed.

However, when trying to add the jar to hibernate Configuration, I get a

```
  org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

The inner exception is related to the hibernate dialect:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

However, I am sure to have specified the `hibernate.dialect` property in the `persistence.xml` file. Below is the code I am using in my application:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration cfg = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
cfg.addJar(new File("path/to/jar.jar"));
cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, could you please tell me if you find this a good approach to create a dynamically updateable schema shared between multiple applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The main point is that, when using EntityManagerFactory (the JPA API), the hibernate persistence provider only reads the persistence.xml configuration files and loads the persistence units that are specified therein.

However, using a hibernate API configuration, hibernate does not read the persistence.xml files, so one will have to explicitly specify all aspects such as dialect, connection parameters etc in the hibernate.cfg.xml file.

However, I managed to work around this issue. Indeed, in the dynamically loaded jar file, one must export the folders (the META-INF especially) and configure a persistence.xml file in there too. However, naming two persistence units the same, their corresponding classes will **not** get merged and neither will any other properties. By default, hibernate will load the first found persistence unit and will treat the identically-named ones as different. So, I created a more flexible core schema that allows access to multiple persistence units, while caching them in something similar to dictionaries. Consequently, for each schema in my application, I will load the corresponding persistence unit while storing all of them in a dictionary-style container, allowing the application to get notified should any changes occur to the underlying jar file.